# SQL Server Express while attaching a database getting error 5120

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express

I have SQL Server Express installed on my local machine. When I try to attach a database file, it's giving me the following error

> Unable to open physical file "C:\Adventures2012_data.mdf. Operating system error 5: 5 (Access is denied) (Microsoft sql server error 5120)

Please let me know how to fix this??

Comment: `Access is denied` is quite a self explanatory error.

Comment: move the file to some other folder having a full permission or execute permission for the SQL service account and then try to attach file.

Answer (score 4):

The minimal permissions needed to attach a database file is 'full control'. If you want to attach the database using SQL Server Management Studio, the account running SSMS must have full control on both the database MDF and LDF files

To grant privileges to files:

1. Right click the file in Windows Explorer
2. Open the **Security** tab
3. Click **Edit**
4. Click **Add** and add the SSMS account
5. Grant **Full control**
6. Go to SSMS and try to attach the file again

You can copy the file to another folder, to avoid C root, you might not have enough permissions there

Comment: Worked for me tooooo. One addition from my end: 
I have multiple databases inside a folder so I Right clicked on the Folder instead of file and follow the above process. All databases inside that folder are working now.

Answer (score 0):

1) right click the .mdf file
2) Propertiest
3) Security
4) edit
5) add
6) Advanced
7) find now
8) everyone
9) okay
10) okay
11) Full controll
12) okey
13) okey
14) right click sql server management studio
15) run as administrator
16) Then Attach.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with the AdventureWorks database. I changed the directory from C:\ to E:\, and then right-clicked on the AdventureWorks database, selected **Security**, and granted the **Full Control** permission to your local users. Finally, you can run SQL Management Studio as Administrator, and attach your database.